# Magento 2 multi website url setup

Tags: magento2, multistore, nginx

I would like to achieve the below URL setup in magento 2 with nginx

```
domain.com/us/          ->  us english store view   (us_en)
domain.com/us/de/       ->  us german store view    (us_de)

domain.com/uk/          ->  uk english store view   (uk_en) 
domain.com/uk/de/       ->  uk german store view    (uk_de)
```

I've created 2 websites and one store for each website and 2 store views for each store. Done the base url setup per Store View.

Tried enabling and disabling "Add Store Code to Urls". Still no luck

Note: I dont want a subdomain approach

The below nginx config doesnt work. results 404 error on magento2.

```
domain vhost.conf

map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    default   us_en;
    ~^/us/de  us_de;
    ~^/us     us_en;
    ~^/uk/de  uk_de;    
    ~^/uk     uk_en;
}

map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_TYPE {
    default   store;
}

<magento_root>/nginx.conf.sample

location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    ....    
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    ...
}
```

Achieved the above structure with apache, by creating the old softlink approach.
But have to get the config done in nginx.

Thanks in Advance.

### Srini

Comment: you just need to add either rewrite or symlink

Comment: Have you figured this out ? Have you tried to set `Add Store Code to Urls` = `No` but set `Base Urls` in each store configuration to `example.com/us/de/`, `example.com/us/`, .. ?

Comment: Have you figured this out, having similar problems here...