# Ho to set multistore configuration in Magento 2 to have domain.com and domain.com/storecode/

Tags: magento2, multistore, nginx, domain

In Magento 2,

How to have the default store to be set on `domain.com`
and other stores to be in directory structure urls like:
`domain.com/uk`, `domain.com/de`, ..

**First approach:**
There is the admin configuration `Admin > Stores > Configuration > GENERAL > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls = Yes`.
But it's a global configuration and can't be set on website level or store level.

Now, what I can have is `domain.com/[default_store_code]/*`.
Actually if I visit `domain.com` it will render urls inside the page as `domain.com/[default_store_code]/path_to_category`, ..

Is it something that I miss here ?

In Nginx specifically I'm interested about.
I don't want to add declarations in Nginx conf to redirect `domain.com/defaut_store_code/*` to `domain.com/*`.
I don't like it and I don't believe there should be an additional redirect just to stay on domain.com/* URL.

**Second approach:**
Another approach that i'm looking at is to set `Add Store Code to Urls = No` and have in admin configuration `Base Url` set to `domain.com` in default store configuration level.
And on store `uk` configuration level to have `Base Url` set to `domain.com/uk/`
The last part it would be to write something in Nginx conf to set store codes and website code by url. Like if I'm on `domain.com/uk/*` than set `MAGE_RUN_CODE` to `uk`

**Update:**
I'm testing the second approach with `Add Store Code to Urls = No`.
I'm using in Nginx the conf bellow to make Magento 2 aware of the store codes.
The static resources like css, js and .html were not working. I set in global configuration `Base URL for Static View Files` = `http://domain.com/static/`
and `Base URL for User Media Files` `http://domain.com/media/`

Inspired from here: [Magento 2 multi website url setup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162485/magento-2-multi-website-url-setup)

```
# in http context of conf
map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    default   default;
    ~^/uk  uk;
}

map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_TYPE {
    default   store;
}

server {
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

    listen 8080;
    server_name domain.com;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /[../path to magento 2];

    # I have tried several try_files and didn't do nothing

    include /[../path to magento 2]/nginx.conf.sample;

    #location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
    #   fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    #}
}
```

This works for me if I put it in the file /[../path to magento 2]/nginx.conf.sample

```
    # Search 'location' line bellow and add the 2 fastcgi_param lines from bellow
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
       ......
       fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
       fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    }
```

Further I'm looking in Magento 2 why it doesn't like to have a directory path before the controller part in URL. And I'll also explore those try_files in conf.

**Update 2**

I've added as an experiment in `\Magento\Store\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor::process()`

```
if ($store->isUseStoreInUrl()) {
    ..
} else {
    if ($store) {
       $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode);
       $pathInfo = '/' . (isset($pathParts[1]) ? $pathParts[1] : '');
       return $pathInfo;
    }
}
```

Store switcher on the page doesn't work well but it rendered the pages ok:
homepage,category page, product page.
It still needs solid research until it's good.

Thank you

Comment: Did you have success with your approach?